# How can I validate parameters before calling "ip route add"?

Tags: networking, ip, routing, iproute

I am using a program which sets etcd parameters which are expanded to calls to "ip route add ..." and I need those calls to succeed without error.  The template uses a format such as:

```
ip route add < route > [ via < gateway > ] dev < interface >
```

I have gotten responses like this:

```
# ip route show
169.254.0.0/16 dev ens192 scope link metric 1002 
172.16.25.64/26 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.25.115 
254.146.247.0/24 dev ens224 scope link 

# ip route add 10.20.30.0/24 via 172.16.25.124 dev ens192
# ip route delete 10.20.30.0/24 via 172.16.25.124 dev ens192
# ip route add 10.20.31.0/24 via 172.16.25.124 dev ens224
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable

# ip route add 10.20.31.0/24 via 254.146.247.1 dev ens224
# ip route delete 10.20.31.0/24 via 254.146.247.1 dev ens224
# ip route add 10.20.30.0/24 via 254.146.247.1 dev ens192
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable

# ping -c 1 172.16.25.124
PING 172.16.25.124 (172.16.25.124) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.25.124: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.294 ms

--- 172.16.25.124 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.294/0.294/0.294/0.000 ms

# ping -c 1 254.146.247.1
PING 254.146.247.1 (254.146.247.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted

--- 254.146.247.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

I am using Python to collect parameters to be stored in an etcd database to execute a populated template with "ip route add..."s when the service which uses the populated configuration file is restarted.  What I am looking for is a way to verify the values to be used for route, gateway and interface, so that when the "ip route add"s are eventually called, they will not fail. In particular, from the example above, I need to know that the gateway ip address 254.146.247.1 is not reachable from interface ens192.

I cannot use ping as the example above shows.  172.16.25.124 is pingable AND can be used as a gateway for interface ens192 but not for ens224. 254.146.247.1 is NOT pingable BUT can be used as a gateway for interface ens224 but not for ens192.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems a bit pointless trying to duplicate what `ip route` already does. I would just let `ip route` tell you what was legal or not. Unless this is just an exercise.

Comment: It is not pointless.  I am writing network configuration scripts in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ but cannot restart the network service without kicking me off.  This is done in a program which collects these parameters and saves them in etcd.  I'd like to validate that the parameters are valid first. There are other processes downstream that will read the parameters from etcd and execute the "ip route add" commands (so the network service will not have to be restarted) AND write a network-script so that those values will be restored on a reboot.

Comment: Mark - i suspect @meuh intimates a redundancy at validation; as i read it, meuh means *it is maybe pointless to validate parameters that ```ip``` validates.* i somewhat agree; if the functionality is not duplicated *(hopefully while improved)* then prevalidating input to elide return conditions is not much of a filter, in my opinion. ```ip``` returns error conditions conditionally; thats what errors are for.

Comment: @mikeserv I think I did not describe my problem correctly so I modified my question.  Basically, I am not able to call "ip route add"; this is done from an expanded template populated from an etcd database.  I only have the ability to save the parameter values - route, gateway and interface - into the etcd database.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

```
#!/bin/bash
IP_RULES_FILE=/tmp/iprules.txt

while read rule
do
   GW=`echo $rule |  awk '{print $6}'`
   ping -c1 $GW 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
   if [ "$?" = 0 ]; then
    $rule
    else
        echo "host $gw is not reachable"
    fi
done < $IP_RULES_FILE
```

- Please store the iproute in file `/tmp/iprules.txt` which are needs to be added.
- The script will get the gateway from given rule and verified reachability before configuring it in server

Comment: Using ping will not work in my example.  As my example illustrates, both gateway are reachable (pingable) from my machine and are reachable from one of the interfaces but not other.  In your example, the ping will succeed but the call to "ip route add" will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by parsing the output of netstat:

```
# netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 ens192
172.16.25.64    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U         0 0          0 ens192
254.146.247.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens224
```

A gateway address for an interface has to come from the destination addresses configured for that interface.  In my example (ip route add 10.20.31.0/24 via 254.146.247.1 dev ens224) works because I chose an ip address (254.146.247.1) from a ip network (254.146.247.0/24) configured for the interface (ens224).